# Убрать рекурсией цифры из строки

Tags: python, строки, рекурсия

Мне нужно при помощи рекурсии убрать все цифры из строки и вернуть перевернутое выражение

Я застрял на следующей рекурсии:

```
def recursion(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    if s[0].isdigit():
        return s.replace(s[0], '')
    return recursion(s[1:]) + s[0]
```

после # идет то, что должно получаться

после ---> то, что получается с моим кодом

```
print(recursion("poo"))  # "oop" ---> это работает
print(recursion("3129047284"))  # '' ---> '129047284'
print(recursion("34e34f7i8l 00r532o23f 4n5ot565hy7p4"))  # "pyhton for life"  --->  '4e 4f7i8l 00r5 2o2 f 4n5ot565hy7p4'
print(recursion("  k 4"))  # " k  "  ---> это получилось
```

Я понял, что он видимо выходит из рекурсии сразу же после первой цифры, но не понимаю, как можно это исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я поменял одну строчку в вашем коде - если цифра, просто её игнорируем

```
    if s[0].isdigit():
        return recursion(s[1:])
```

и всё работает

```
def recursion(s):
    if s == "":
        return s
    if s[0].isdigit():
        return recursion(s[1:])
    return recursion(s[1:]) + s[0]
```